# How do you do constrained non-linear least squares in R

Tags: r, optimization, lasso-regression

I am fitting a non-linear least squares model in R.  I wish to minimize $(Y - f(Xb))^2$ where $f$ is a nonlinear monotone differentiable function, $X$ is a set of features and $b$ is the parameter vector.  Is there a way of doing this with constraints on $b$?  I want to constrain $b$ to be greater than 0 and I want L1-style shrinkage of some of the elements to 0.  Is there a way of doing this in R? `nls()` doesn't allow for constraints.

Comment: And how are you parameterizing $f$()? Is it a polynomial, a spline, ...?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert $\|\boldsymbol{x}\|_1$ in your objective by putting a constraint on each element of $\boldsymbol{x}$, into a simple sum and then use quadprog to solve the problem.